# ChartJS 2.6 - Change color of bar in Bar chart programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js2, chart.js

Can anyone please show me how to change the background/hoverColor of a given bar chart color?  I'm logging out the chart object to the console, and I do not see anything obvious that I can set to accomplish this.  I want to be able to change a column color in a bar chart on demand programmatically.

All I can see in the chart object is
`chart.data.datasets[0]._meta.data[0]._view.backgroundColor` attribute.  But there must be an easier way than to travel all the way down the object like this, isn't there?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access an array of the background colors directly in the `datasets` object:

```
chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0]
```

Example usage:
https://jsfiddle.net/6d0jsyxu/1/

Comment: A note: Don't forget to call `chart.update();` after making the change.